# Integer overflow trapping with LLVM?

Tags: llvm, undefined-behavior, llvm-ir, integer-overflow

I'm creating a statically compiled programming language, and I'm using LLVM as its backend. I want my language to trap/crash whenever integer overflow occurs.

I'm aware of things like [llvm.sadd.with.overflow](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-sadd-with-overflow-intrinsics), but I don't think that's an optimal/efficient solution. That function returns a struct of two values, instead of just giving me direct access to the OF register flag. Ideally, after each arithmetic operation I would just have a "JO" assembly instruction to trap whenever integer overflow occurs. This is exactly what clang's [UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) does. However, I'm compiling to LLVM IR, not C or C++.

How can I use the UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer (or accomplish something equivalent) to handle integer overflow, directly within LLVM IR?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm aware of things like llvm.sadd.with.overflow, but I don't think that's an optimal/efficient solution. [...] Ideally, after each arithmetic operation I would just have a "JO" assembly instruction to trap whenever integer overflow occurs. This is exactly what clang's UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer does.

What the UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer does is to generate calls to `llvm.sadd.with.overflow`. You can easily verify this by compiling the following C program with `-fsanitize=undefined` and looking at the generated LLVM code:

bla.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int x;
  scanf("%d", &x);
  printf("%d\n", x+1);
  return 0;
}
```

Command line:

```
clang -fsanitize=undefined -emit-llvm -O2 -S bla.c
```

bla.ll (excerpt):

```llvm
  %5 = call { i32, i1 } @llvm.sadd.with.overflow.i32(i32 %4, i32 1), !nosanitize !8
  %6 = extractvalue { i32, i1 } %5, 0, !nosanitize !8
  %7 = extractvalue { i32, i1 } %5, 1, !nosanitize !8
  br i1 %7, label %8, label %10, !prof !9, !nosanitize !8

; <label>:8:                                      ; preds = %0
  %9 = zext i32 %4 to i64, !nosanitize !8
  call void @__ubsan_handle_add_overflow(i8* bitcast ({ { [6 x i8]*, i32, i32 }, { i16, i16, [6 x i8] }* }* @1 to i8*), i64 %9, i64 1) #5, !nosanitize !8
```

`sadd.with.overflow` will end up as a regular `incl` instruction¹ and the `br i1 %7` as a `jo` in the generated x64 assembly, so that's exactly what you want.

---

¹ It would be a proper add instruction if I added something other than 1 in the C code, of course.